# Get google Search position

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

i want to find on which page my link is located for given seatch word with out navigating to each page. Is it possible i am using winforms c#

lets say i have to find link facebook.com for search word social networking and see on which google page is this link present

Comment: That code is very wrong.  Also, it won't look beyond the first page.

Answer (score 2):

Dude, you should not parse HTML with regexp. I'm not explaining why here, there's much information on why around here. A solution to get all results using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and XPATH:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetResults(string html) {
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//span[@class='tl']/h3/a"))
    {
        var value = link["href"].Value;
        yield return value;
     }
 }
```

This will fetch all links matching our XPATH `//span[@class='tl']/h3/a` (SERP items, no PPC etc.) and return the href attribute.

A easier way to get your html is using WebClient, like:

```
using(var wc = new WebClient())
{
   return wc.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(searchTerm));
}
```

You obviously need to do the downloading and comparison yourself, but this should get you going.

Comment: its not about getting links its about finding link present at what number of page ;)

Answer (score 0):

try using http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html  - although it's limited to 100 queries per day